# Create a RadDataGrid in Xamarin form using Telerik

Tags: c#, xaml, telerik, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Hi I'm a newbie in Xamarin Forms. I googled a lot before asking this question but couldn't able to find suitable answer.

I'm trying to create a piechart in Xamarin Forms for that I installed the Telerik UI for xamarin using Nuget.

**CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="DemoApp.DashboardPage" xmlns:telerikChart="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Chart;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Chart">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <telerikChart:RadPieChart>
          <telerikChart:RadPieChart.Series>
            <telerikChart:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" ShowLabels="true">
                  <telerikChart:PieSeries.ValueBinding>
                    <telerikChart:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="ProductQuantity"/>
                  </telerikChart:PieSeries.ValueBinding>
            </telerikChart:PieSeries>
          </telerikChart:RadPieChart.Series>
    </telerikChart:RadPieChart>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

But when I run the I'm getting error saying "**System..IO.FileNotFoundxception** has been thrown  Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.XamarinForms.Chart' or one of its dependencies.

Can anybody tell how i can solve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a Xamarin Forms application you must install the package in all the projects, the Forms one and the native ones.

This error usually happens because you installed only the portable libraries package which is only a facade to the real ones.

Comment: Thanks. I installed the package in native one but now i couldn't able to run the app. I'm getting "**Java.Lang.NullPointerException** attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.contentFrameLayout.setId(int)' on a null object reference." Can u tell what to do

Comment: It seems you're using a library which is not compatible with API level 23, this post reports the exact same problem: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42959/getting-nullpointerexception-with-appcompatactivity-after-june-2nd-update